# Burninate [scale]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Right now we have the [scaling](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scaling) tag and the [scale](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scale) tag, which I think is unnecessary.

To me scaling is a better tag, has 69 questions, 1 follower, and a wiki tag. Scale, on the other hand, has 17 questions, no followers, and no wiki.

Can the scale tag please be deleted, or at least merged with scaling?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[scaling](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scaling) has now been merged into [resize](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resize) which was a more common tag for the same questions. It was also made a synonym to avoid future instances.

Answer (score 3):

I think these are two different tags to a degree.

[scaling](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scaling) refers more to changing the dimensions of an object/shape/etc. Being a verb it is different than the noun.

Where as [scale](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scale) could mean *drawing* something at a ratio of the desired size. As in, create "to scale".

Admittedly these are kind of minor differences, but they are differences.

It doesn't make a whole lot of difference if one goes or not to me. Just pointing out that these *are* indeed different to many users.

Comment: I understand the distinction you're making, but I feel like one tag is sufficient for both intentions

Comment: Maybe the tag scale should be renamed scaled drawings or to scale. And i dissagree with merging